# mysql query LIKE condition against a concat

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

Im trying to run a query something like the following statement but either I can't figure out the correct syntax or it's not doable:

```
SELECT 
    id, first_name, last_name, 
    concat(first_name,' ',last_name) AS full_name
FROM mytable 
WHERE full_name LIKE '%scott%'
```

which is it? If its doable can I get a little help on the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a field computed in the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause, because most (if not all) RDBMS evaluate the `WHERE` clause before the `SELECT`.

You probably want :

```
SELECT 
    id, first_name, last_name, 
    CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) AS full_name
FROM mytable 
WHERE CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE '%scott%'
```

Which can also be expressed :

```
SELECT 
    id, first_name, last_name, 
    CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) AS full_name
FROM mytable 
WHERE first_name LIKE '%scott%' OR last_name like '%scott%'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that I can think of you can do this:

1. You could run the `LIKE` against both the `first_name` and `last_name` columns separately using an `OR`, or
2. You could use a sub-query to concatenate the fields first, or
3. You could run the `LIKE` against the concatenated fields.

For the first solution:

```
SELECT  id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        concat(first_name,' ',last_name) AS full_name
  FROM  mytable
  WHERE (first_name LIKE '%scott%' OR
        last_name LIKE '%scott%');
```

For the second solution:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  (
        SELECT  id,
                first_name,
                last_name,
                concat(first_name,' ',last_name) AS full_name
          FROM  mytable
        ) a
  WHERE full_name LIKE '%scott%';
```

The third involves including `WHERE CONCAT(...) LIKE '%scott%'`.

I would personally use the second solution as I believe it would be more efficient, and I think it looks more presentable.  They'll all work though so it's up to you.